# How to find the folder reference and add appointment to non default calendar/folder through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, directory, pst

I've been building some VBA for a calendar events to be generated through an excel macro. My issue is that I want the event to go to a non default calendar but i'm struggling through my reading here to know how to reference the folder.... and then reference it correctly!

The path for the calendar  is   "\Res-Cal\Calendar"

The below starting code works for the default calendar

```
    Sub CreateEventFromExcel()

    Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Provider As Object
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim StartDate As String
    Dim StartTime As String
    Dim Title As String

    StartDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
    StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
    Title = "Ref: " & Range("F10") & " -- " & ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) & " -- " & Range("C15") & "/" & Range("L15")

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olEvent = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set Provider = Range("L15")

    With olEvent
    .Subject = Title
    .Start = StartDate & " " & Format(StartTime, "h:mm")
    .Duration = 60
    .Categories = "1_Agent Confirmation Sent"
    .Display

    End With

    End Sub
```

WHAT IT LOOKED LIKE I SHOULD BE DOING

```
    Sub CreateEventFromExcel()

    Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Provider As Object
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim StartDate As String
    Dim StartTime As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim olNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim olFolder as Object

    StartDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
    StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
    Title = "Ref: " & Range("F10") & " -- " & ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) & " -- " & Range("C15") & "/" & Range("L15")

    Set olApp = new Outlook.Application
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.Getnamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    Set olEvent = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set Provider = Range("L15")

    With olFolder
    .Subject = Title
    .Start = StartDate & " " & Format(StartTime, "h:mm")
    .Duration = 60
    .Categories = "1_Agent Confirmation Sent"
    .Display

    End With
    End Sub
```

My first question is how do I find the xxxxxxx?   This is a different PST in outlook "Res-Cal"

[image]

I did try other posts for finding the missing string here but they did not return anything but instead just displayed my outlook folder structure in totality.

I thought I was to use folder # so did randomly try some numbers from 1-20 but none worked so I'm down the wrong path.

Any help would be much appreciated as creating in the default calendar is not going to cut it for what I need.

Thanks!

Updated Code below

```
Sub EMAILQUERY()

Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Provider As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim StartDate As String
Dim StartTime As String
Dim Title As String
Dim olNameSpace As Namespace
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim MAPIFolder As Object

StartDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
Title = "Ref: " & Range("F10") & " -- " & ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) & " -- " & Range("C15") & "/" & Range("L15")


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").Folders("Calendar")


Set olEvent = MAPIFolder.Items.Add()

Set Provider = Range("L15")



With olFolder
    .Subject = Title
    .Start = StartDate & " " & Format(StartTime, "h:mm")
    .Duration = 60
    .Categories = "1_Agent Confirmation Sent"
    .Display


End With

End Sub
```

Latest updated code

```
Sub EMAILQUERY()

Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Provider As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim StartDate As String
Dim StartTime As String
Dim Title As String
Dim olNameSpace As Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.folder


StartDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
Title = "Ref: " & Range("F10") & " -- " & ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) & " -- " & Range("C15") & "/" & Range("L15")


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").Folders("Calendar")

olNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("XXXXXXXX").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

Set olEvent = olFolder.Items.Add()

Set Provider = Range("L15")



With olFolder
    .Subject = Title
    .Start = StartDate & " " & Format(StartTime, "h:mm")
    .Duration = 60
    .Categories = "1_Agent Confirmation Sent"
    .Display


End With

End Sub
```

Updated

```
Sub EMAILQUERY()

Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Provider As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim StartDate As String
Dim StartTime As String
Dim Title As String
Dim olNameSpace As Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.folder


StartDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
Title = "Ref: " & Range("F10") & " -- " & ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) & " -- " & Range("C15") & "/" & Range("L15")

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetRootFolder.Folders("Calendar")

Set olEvent = olFolder.Items.Add()

Set Provider = Range("L15")


With olFolder
    .Subject = Title
    .Start = StartDate & " " & Format(StartTime, "h:mm")
    .Duration = 60
    .Categories = "1_Agent Confirmation Sent"
    .Display


End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Calendar ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789601/how-to-find-calendar-id)

Comment: For the folder path alternative, responders may find it easier if you edit the post to add the folder path. Select the calendar then enter `?ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath` in the immediate window. Replace any email address with a dummy.

Comment: Thanks for that code Niton - the path is "\Res-Cal\Calendar"

Comment: Focusing on the folder name option see Dmitry's answer `set folder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)` . Otherwise `Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetRootFolder.Folders("Calendar")`.

Comment: @niton where are you referring when you say replace any email address with a dummy? Thanks

Comment: @niton thats looking good and not getting errors there with that new code! I'm now getting a different error which relates to where i'm setting the variables for the event itself (title etc). In the past when I created Emails from VBA i used the "olMail" to set the variables which was "Dim outlook.MailItem". However in code i was looking at am i right to have it as olFolder in this case? Reposted code.

Comment: I should clarify the new error is on the    .subject = Title      Line where it says "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: This error message is clear `olFolder` does not have a subject property. Review your code to see the item you added to `olFolder`.

Comment: My error was with saying olFolder in that last part. I was mixing up between code i made and borrowed. Changed to olEvent instead and the Calendar  item now displays correctly in Res-Cal. Thank you very much for all your responses and clarifications!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the folder name option where folderpath is "\Res-Cal\Calendar"
rather than the `.GetFolderFromID` option (`Debug.Print ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID`).

With a folder not under the mailbox.

```
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetRootFolder.Folders("Calendar")
```

rather than default folder code

```
Set folder = olNameSpace.Stores("someone@somewhere.com").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
```

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub EMAILQUERY()

' Early binding requires reference to Outlook XX.X Object Library
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Dim Title As String
Dim olNameSpace As Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder

Title = "Title"

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetRootFolder.Folders("Calendar")

Set olEvent = olFolder.Items.Add()

With olEvent
    .Subject = Title
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)` (which creates the appointment in the default calendar folder), use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add()`.

Assuming the store name is `"Res-Cal"`, and the folder in question is a top level folder, the target folder can be retrieved using

```
set folder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").Folders("Calendar")
```

or

```
set folder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - I tried this and  also added "Dim MAPIFolder As Object" (hopefully right?) .

I then had an "object variable or With block variable not set" on the revised olEvent line

I also got the follow error at the new olFolder line suggested :    "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any thoughts. I should note I'm a newbie (if this isnt already plain to see)

Comment: Please post your updated code.

Comment: Thanks. Edited original post with an update. I hope that's how Im supposed to show updated code!

Comment: the line `Set olEvent = MAPIFolder.Items.Add()` needs to be `Set olEvent = olFolder.Items.Add()`. MAPIFolder in my reply referred to the MAPIFolder type - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder?view=outlook-pia

Comment: Thanks. I replaced that and still get a "object doesnt support this property" at the o"Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").Folders("Calendar")" line. I reposted the code. I alos changed DIM olFolder as Outlook.folder (MAPIfolder doesnt look to be usable anymore). Not sure if thats right but saw it in other scripts in this space..
Confirmed the path is "\Res-Cal\Calendar" per Niton suggestion

Comment: Hi Dmitry - per above comments section we got this to work with the combination of help. Thanks very much for responding!