# Send MS Project Tasks to a different Outlook calendar instead of my default

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-project

This code sends MS Project Tasks to Outlook as events.

I want to set it to a different calendar instead of my default.

The original code:

```vb
Sub Export_Selection_To_OL_Appointments()
Dim myTask As Task
Dim myItem As Object
    
On Error Resume Next
Set myOLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  
For Each myTask In ActiveSelection.Tasks
    Set myItem = myOLApp.CreateItem(1)
    With myItem
        .Start = myTask.Start
        .End = myTask.Finish
        .Subject = " Rangebank PS " & myTask.Name
        .Categories = myTask.Project
        .Body = myTask.Notes
        .Save
    End With
Next myTask

End Sub
```

Tried code I found online.

Comment: Not sure why this has a close vote as it seems to meet SO guidelines. Anyway, hopefully an Outlook vba expert can chime in on how to add a calendar entry to a specific calendar.

Comment: Should I do something to fix that?

Comment: You could include the code that you tried and explain where it’s not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the folder reference and add appointment to non default calendar/folder through Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77048056/how-to-find-the-folder-reference-and-add-appointment-to-non-default-calendar-fol)

Comment: Hi Niton. Thanks for the reply. I think it does help but I am a novice. As far as I can tell if I add this line of code

set folder = olNameSpace.Stores("Res-Cal").Folders("Calendar")

Res-Cal being the name of the calendar then that should do it?

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how you could reference a non-default Outlook folder to add an item.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NonDefaultFolder_Add_Not_Create()

Dim myOlApp As Object
Dim myDefaultStore As Object

Dim nonDefaultCalendar As Object
Dim myItem As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Consider this mandatory.
' Limit the scope of the error bypass to the minimum number of lines.
' Ideally the scope is zero lines.
On Error GoTo 0

If Not myOlApp Is Nothing Then

    Set myDefaultStore = myOlApp.Session.defaultStore
    Debug.Print myDefaultStore
    
    ' This references a calendar on the same level as the default calendar
    Set nonDefaultCalendar = myOlApp.Session.Folders(myDefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Calendar Name")
    nonDefaultCalendar.Display
    
    ' Add to non-default folders (or create in the default then copy or move)
    Set myItem = nonDefaultCalendar.Items.Add
    With myItem
        .Subject = " Rangebank PS "
        .Display
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "Error creating Outlook object."
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Niton, so where you have "nonDefaultCalendar" I should rename that to the name of the non default calendar as it is in Outlook?

Comment: If my assumption about the location of the calendar is correct then replace "Calendar Name" with "name of the non default calendar as it is in Outlook". If not sufficient, edit the question to indicate the path to the calendar as it appears in the navigation pane.

Comment: The solution depends on the location of the non-default folder. See for example [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox). If more is needed, edit your post with the folder path.